# QTcreator + Cimg.h = Error opening .jpg .png

Tags: linux, qt, jpeg, qt-creator, cimg

I'm stating to use QTcreator and for my application I'm having to use CImg.h to 'play' with some images, but when I try to load some image this error appear:

```
"[CImg] *** CImgIOException *** [instance(0,0,0,0,(nil),non-shared)] CImg<unsigned char>::load(): Failed to open file 'image.jpg'.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cimg_library::CImgIOException'
what():  [instance(0,0,0,0,(nil),non-shared)] CImg<unsigned char>::load(): Failed to open file 'image.jpg' "



void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{

    cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char> img01("image.jpg");
    img01.display("image");


}
```

I had already installed ImageMagick but didn't solved. Someone can help me please?

(I'm using the newest version of Fedora.)

Comment: You forgot to explain how it is Qt related. Those two lines work for you in a simple main function, or ... ?

Comment: It looks like the image file just isn't found. Try with an absolute path. And catch that exception.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld OMG I just putted the full path and worked, thanks very much... 3 days working on that and was only this . thank you very much folks!

Answer (score 1):

Following the tip of @FrankOsterfeld i just used the full path and the image opened! thnks guys!